# Get Data in Fragment through Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

In this problem I want to get Data from My API

In which I get Data from Retrofit

I want to show data in RecyclerView in Fragment Tabs but how can I send data from activity to Fragment

This is all I have tried

**Retrofit call which provide me ArrayList of my posts**

```
getMainApp().swiftAPI.getPosts().enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Post>>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Post>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@DashboardActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Post>>?, response: Response<ArrayList<Post>>?) {
                if (response?.isSuccessful!!){

                }
            }
```

**PagesFragment**

```
val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false)
        val video_recyclerview = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pages_rcv) as RecyclerView // Add this
        video_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        video_recyclerview.adapter = PagesAdapter()
        return rootView
```

I want to Know if there is any way possible to send ArrayList to fragment cause my data is in ArrayList
[image: As shown in Picture]

Comment: you are call api into fragment why you are sending data activity to fragment

Comment: @AndroidTeam i use special method for retrofit calls as you can see in My Retrofit call can you provide me retrofit call Code ?

Comment: you want pass data from activity to fragment

Comment: @AndroidTeam data is in ArrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an interface in your activity and let the fragment implement the interface. You can follow this example on my github: [ActivityToFragmentCommunication](https://github.com/ngallazzi/ActivityToFragmentCommunicationExample)

Basically, in your activity define:

```java
  public interface DataLoadedListener {
        public void onDataLoaded(ArrayList<Post> posts);
    }
```

Then, make your fragment implement the interface like below:

```java
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.DataLoadedListener {

  // your fragment code
}
```

Finally in the onCreate() method of your activity:

```java
// Create new fragment and transaction
        mExampleFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        // setting mExampleFragment as data load listener
        mDataLoadedListener = (DataLoadedListener) mExampleFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContainer, mExampleFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

        // load data after click
        btLoadData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadData();
                // notify attached fragment
                mDataLoadedListener.onDataLoaded(myStrings);
            }
        });
```

Comment: please check your link

Comment: My friend used this code to transfer i have special retrofit setting for it

Answer (score 0):

First check `currentFragment` in your activity class. You will get the **fragment reference object** in your activity class . so the example will like below:

Suppose you have a fragment called `DataFragment` and you have a reference `mDataFragment` in your activity class. now when you get data in your activity class you will call `((DataFragment)mDataFragment).passData(yourDataList).` Remember `passData()` is a public method in your fragment class. Then you can add data in `adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on Android, I would recommend the ViewModel component which makes it really easy to communicate between a activity and it's fragments.

First add the package to your app

```
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
```

Then create a ViewModel class

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Post>> posts = new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Post>>();
}
```

Now in the fragment subscribe to it.

```
 public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.posts.observe(this, { posts ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
 }
```

Then set the value in your MainActivity as shown below and voila you have the data in your fragment. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java)

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
        // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

        MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.users.setValue(posts);
    }
}
```